# Is Apocalypse's power-buffing effect permanent?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse, marvel

One of Apocalypse's advertised abilities is the power to buff any other mutant's powers, which he used primarily on his four principal followers. Can this effect be permanent?

> We know he used it on Charles Xavier, and it's a temporary effect, but does it have the option to be permanent on, say, Magneto or Storm and thus survive his death?

Answer (score 2):

Currently this is unknown, the only two observations which can be made after/during his defeat is that:

1.Storms hair still is white, instead of the being black before the power up.

2.Angel's wings never reverted back to just feathers.

Also in regards to the comics, Angel could switch between Angel and Archangel forms (the latter being his powered up form)